# A "Replace" sort problem. Basic but haunts me

Tags: replacement

Here's my problem when doing my codes.

I need an output similar to `{{p->1},{p->2},{p->3},{p->4}}`,where `p` is a generic variable. How can I achieve such results?

If anyone knows how, plz help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
{p -> #} & /@ Range[4]
```

> {{p -> 1}, {p -> 2}, {p -> 3}, {p -> 4}}

Also

```
Table[{p -> i}, {i, 4}]
Array[{p -> #} &, 4]
Range[4] /. x_Integer :> {p -> x}
List /@ Thread[p -> Range[4]]
```

all give

> {{p -> 1}, {p -> 2}, {p -> 3}, {p -> 4}}

Comment: Thank you three thousand times!

Comment: @Robin, you are welcome..